# DiracDelta convergence in 3D - Cartesian vs. spherical coordinates

Tags: symbolic, vector-calculus, calculus-and-analysis

Integrating DiracDelta in 3D in Cartesian coordinates works just fine i.e. gives `vecf[{x, y, z}]`

```
vecr = {x, y, z};
vecrp = {xp, yp, zp};        

Assuming[(vecr | vecrp | vecf[_]) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals], 
Simplify[Integrate[DiracDelta[-xp + x] DiracDelta[-yp + y] DiracDelta[-zp + 
 z]*vecf[vecrp], {xp, -Infinity, Infinity}, {yp, -Infinity, Infinity}, {zp, - 
Infinity, Infinity}]]]
```

However, the same integral in Spherical coordinates does not converge

```
 x = r*Sqrt[1 - μ^2]*Cos[ϕ];
 y = r*Sqrt[1 - μ^2]*Sin[ϕ];
 z = r*μ;

 xp = rp*Sqrt[1 - μp^2]*Cos[ϕp];
 yp = rp*Sqrt[1 - μp^2]*Sin[ϕp];
 zp = rp*μp;

 J = rp^2*Sqrt[1 - μp^2]
 Assuming[(vecr | vecrp | vecf[_]) ∈ Vectors[3, Reals],
 Simplify[Integrate[DiracDelta[-xp + x] DiracDelta[-yp + y] DiracDelta[-zp + 
 z]*vecf[vecrp]*J, {rp, 0, Infinity}, {μp, -1, 1}, {ϕp, 0, 
 2*Pi}]]]
```

I have also tried using `Cos[θ]` instead of `μ`.

Comment: If you look in Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) , you will know that the integral under consideration  has no sense. Upgrade your math.

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: The quote "Adding and multiplying distributions
Distributions may be multiplied by real numbers and added together, so they form a real vector space. Distributions may also be multiplied by infinitely differentiable functions, but it is not possible to define a product of general distributions that extends the usual pointwise product of functions and has the same algebraic properties". Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point. If we start from the integrand in Cartesian coordinates dxdydz Delta(x-xp)Delta(y-yp)Delta(z-zp) vecf(rp) and change coordinates to Spherical, we get dr dTheta DPhi J Delta(r-rp)Delta(Theta-Thetap)Delta(Phi-Phip)/J vecf(vec(rp)), which upon integrating gives vecf(vec(r)), where J is a Jacobian. The question is why Mathematica does not do this automatically. 

Take a look at e.g. http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~ercelebi/mp03.pdf

Comment: This is not my point. Up to Wiki, the integrand (as the product of three distributions) is not defined at all. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: But it is defined in the context of Dirac Deltra distribution, at the physicist level of rigor at least. Take a look at the attached document or any textbook on mathematical methods in physics e.g. Riley, Hobson, Bence, 13.1.3. Anyhow, Mathematica does NOT have problem with this product in Cartesian coordinates or in suitably prepared form in Spherical coordinates and my question is how to make automatic transition from first one to the second one.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot discuss with you anymore.

Comment: @user64494 Multiplying the distributions `DiracDelta[-xp + x] DiracDelta[-yp + y] DiracDelta[-zp + z]` makes sense indeed for the integration variables are with respect to different coordinate directions. The resulting distribution is $\delta_{x_p,y_p,z_p}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. One cannot define a product of distributions _in general_ but for two given ones, one can try to decide wether that is possible or not. There is actually a whole theory about that (e.g. see works by Hörmander). I would appreciate if you would hold back yourself a bit in the future and to try to be a bit more polite.

Comment: @user64494 And `Integrate[DiracDelta[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]` is Mathematica's (and not only Mathematica's) way to write the pairing $\langle \delta_0, 1\rangle$.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Can you base your statement by arguments and exact references? How about Integrate[DiracDelta[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]  which is simply ignorant?  Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Henrik Shumacher: BTW, we read in  Mathematica help "DiracDelta[x] returns 0 for all real numeric x other than 0". Nothing about any pairing.

Comment: @user64494 This "somebody" must have moderator priviledges. If I were you, I would start now to be a bit more careful. For the references: See [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Multiplication_of_distributions) and [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Wave_front). Again, in particular the works by Hörmander are relevant.

Comment: I read in the first reference "pairs of distributions with disjoint singular support" Do DiracDelta[x] and DiracDelta[y] have such singular supports?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83704/discussion-between-henrik-schumacher-and-user64494).

Comment: Somebody edited my above comment which was as follows "Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you in such manner. BTW, the notation Integrate[DiracDelta[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}] is simply ignorant: eg see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function " . See https://dropbox.com/s/9id0ocydludljdy/screen%2026.09.18.docx?dl=0 and https://dropbox.com/s/uzyh131wkagvh86/screen%202%2026.09.18.docx?dl=‌​0 This is not a good

Answer (score 1):

*More an extended comment than an answer.*

Hmm. What I can tell is that you do not apply the transformation formula correctly. The Jacobi determinant should look like this:

```
Jac = D[{xp, yp, zp}, {{rp, μp, ϕp}, 1}];
J = Simplify[Abs[Det[Jac]], {-1 < μp < 1, rp > 0}];
```

> rp^2

But that doesn't cause the problem. Apparently, Mathematica cannot handle `DiracDelta`s with complicated arguments correctly. I agree with user64494 in that respect, that Mathematica does not treat distributions correctly in all cases. Admittedly, it is not that easy to teach Mathematica that

> rp^2 DiracDelta[r μ - rp μp, r Sqrt[1 - μ^2] Cos[ϕ] - rp Sqrt[1 - μp^2] Cos[ϕp], r Sqrt[1 - μ^2] Sin[ϕ] - rp Sqrt[1 - μp^2] Sin[ϕp]]

can be simplied to

> DiracDelta[r - rp , μ - μp, ϕ - ϕp]

You might be better off by realizing that "integrating" against

`DiracDelta[-xp + x] DiracDelta[-yp + y] DiracDelta[-zp + z]` (or, equivalently, against `DiracDelta[x - xp , y - yp, z - zp]`) means actually a point evaluation. 
In mathematical terms:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta_{x_0} \, \varphi \, \mathrm{d} x := \langle \delta_{x_0}, \varphi \rangle  := \varphi(x_0) \quad \text{for $\varphi \in C^0_{\mathrm{cpt}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.}$$

The integral sign is used only because one can obtain the action of $\delta_{x_0}$ on as limit of suitable sequences of so-called mollifiers (in the topology of weak-*-convergence).

This stays a point evaluation under pullback along coordinate transformations. In mathematical terms: If $\varPhi$ is a diffeomorphism then

$$\varPhi^* \delta_{x_0} = \delta_{\varPhi^{-1}(x_0)}.$$

Things get more involved if the transformation $\varPhi$ is not a diffeomorphism. This may also be a reason why a correct Mathematica implementation is so hard to obtain.

But maybe other users know of a suitable workaround...?

Comment: I'd like to repeat that the integral under consideration has no sense in traditional math (See the comments to the question for more details. ).